# Data repeats in section of UItableview

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, sections

I have a UITableView with two sections and four rows. Each section is supposed to have two rows content.
It all works fine except for the fact that the items are repeated in section 2:

[image]

However, I want to have it like this:

[image]

My code looks as follows:

**swift 4**

```
// structure for serverData type
struct serverData {
    var structHosts: String
    var structStatusImagesMain: String
    var structServerStatusMain: String
}
```

The variables to fill cells and sections:

```
// data filled in my array "section" and in my array "myServerInfo" of type serverData    
let sections = ["Section 1", "Section 2"]
let myServerInfo = [
    serverData(structHosts: "www.google.com", structStatusImagesMain: "error", structServerStatusMain: "Error "), 
    serverData(structHosts: "www.amazon.com", structStatusImagesMain: "error", structServerStatusMain: "Error "), 
    serverData(structHosts: "www.ebay.com", structStatusImagesMain: "error", structServerStatusMain: "Error "), 
    serverData(structHosts: "www.apple.comt", structStatusImagesMain: "error", structServerStatusMain: "Error ")
]
```

These are the table configurations:

```
// table functions    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = serverStatusTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "serverStatusCell", for: indexPath)

        let lblDescribtion : UILabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(6) as! UILabel
        let lblServerStatus : UILabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(8) as! UILabel
        let imgServer : UIImageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(7) as! UIImageView

                if myServerInfo .isEmpty {
                    print("myServerInfo is empty: ", myServerInfo)
                } else {
                    lblDescribtion.text = myServerInfo[indexPath.row].structHosts
                    imgServer.image = UIImage(named: myServerInfo[indexPath.row].structStatusImagesMain)
                    lblServerStatus.text  = myServerInfo[indexPath.row].structServerStatusMain
                }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Start by organizing your data model into an array of arrays matching how you want it to appear in the table view.

Comment: The output is repeated because you don't consider the `section` property of the `indexPath`. By the way: `viewWithTag` is outdated for a couple of years. Design a custom cell in IB and use outlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three lines:

```
lblDescribtion.text = myServerInfo[indexPath.row].structHosts
imgServer.image = UIImage(named: myServerInfo[indexPath.row].structStatusImagesMain)
lblServerStatus.text  = myServerInfo[indexPath.row].structServerStatusMain
```

There are 2 sections, each with 2 rows in your table. They map to an array of 4 elements. So `index.section` goes from 0 to 1, `index.row` also goes from 0 to 1, meaning 4 total, matching the length of the array.

You need to do that translation correctly:

```
let index = indexPath.section * 2 + indexPath.row

lblDescribtion.text = myServerInfo[index].structHosts
imgServer.image = UIImage(named: myServerInfo[index].structStatusImagesMain)
lblServerStatus.text  = myServerInfo[index].structServerStatusMain
```

One warning though: the way you structure the data means a lot of troubles if you want each section to have differing number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

1) First you have to create struct for section data

```
Struct SectionData {
     Let title: String
     Let data: [serverData]
```

}

```
// structure for serverData type
struct serverData {
    var structHosts: String
    var structStatusImagesMain: String
    var structServerStatusMain: String
}
```

2) then we fill data for every section title

```
    // data filled in my array "section" and in my array "myServerInfo" of type serverData    

let myServerInfo = [SectionData]()
Let section1 = SectionData(title: "section1", data: 
    serverData(structHosts: "www.google.com", structStatusImagesMain: "error", structServerStatusMain: "Error "), 
    serverData(structHosts: "www.amazon.com", structStatusImagesMain: "error", structServerStatusMain: "Error "))

Let section2 = SectionData(title: "section2", data: 
    serverData(structHosts: "www.ebay.com", structStatusImagesMain: "error", structServerStatusMain: "Error "), 
    serverData(structHosts: "www.apple.comt", structStatusImagesMain: "error", structServerStatusMain: "Error "))

myServerInfo.append(section1)
myServerInfo.append(section2)
```

3)confuguration tableView

```
// table functions    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return myServerInfi[section].title
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myServerInfo.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myServerInfo[section].data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = serverStatusTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "serverStatusCell", for: indexPath)

    let lblDescribtion : UILabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(6) as! UILabel
    let lblServerStatus : UILabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(8) as! UILabel
    let imgServer : UIImageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(7) as! UIImageView

            if myServerInfo .isEmpty {
                print("myServerInfo is empty: ", myServerInfo)
            } else {
                lblDescribtion.text = myServerInfo[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].structHosts
                imgServer.image = UIImage(named: myServerInfo[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].structStatusImagesMain)
                lblServerStatus.text  = myServerInfo[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].structServerStatusMain
            }

    return cell
}
```